# Laplace transform of unknown integral (function of time)

Tags: python, transform, sympy, integral

I need to calculate the Laplace transform of an integral function. It seems that sympy is not yet able to understand that.

Assuming the following:

```
from sympy import *
s, t = symbols('s t')
I = Function('I')(t)
eq1 = integrate(I, t)
transforms.laplace_transform(eq1, t, s)
```

The solution should be: `I(s) / s`

However, sympy gives: `LaplaceTransform(Integral(I(t), t), t, s)`

It seems to be an open issue [Issue 7219](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7219). Is there any work around?

Comment: Regarding a workaround: how about Eric Wieser's "crappy implementation" on the github issue?

Comment: That seems to work only with derivatives. Tried that already and it gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [the issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7219) hasn't been fixed yet.

However, we can give a "crappy workaround" based on the ["crappy implementation"](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7219#issuecomment-154768904) of Eric Wieser given for derivatives. Note, however, that the original snippet doesn't seem to work for derivatives either, because the internal representation of higher order derivatives seems to have changed since the snippet was posted.

Here's my "crappy" workaround that catches only the simplest of cases (derivatives only with respect to `t`, indefinite integrals only with respect to `t`, where `t` is the variable on which the Laplace transform acts):

```
from sympy import *

def laplace(e, t, s):
    """Hacked-up Laplace transform that handles derivatives and integrals

    Updated generalization of https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7219#issuecomment-154768904
    """

    res = laplace_transform(e, t, s, noconds=True)
    wf = Wild('f')
    lw = LaplaceTransform(wf, t, s)

    for exp in res.find(lw):
        e = exp.match(lw)[wf]
        args = e.args

        if isinstance(e, Derivative):
            # for derivative check that there's only d/dt^n with n>0
            if len(args) == 2 and args[1][0] == t:
                n = args[1][1]
                if n > 0:
                    newexp = s**n * LaplaceTransform(e.args[0], t, s)
                res = res.replace(exp, newexp)

        elif isinstance(e, Integral):
            # for integral check that there's only n consecutive indefinite integrals w.r.t. t
            if all(len(arg) == 1 and arg[0] == t for arg in args[1:]):
                newexp = s**(-len(args[1:])) * LaplaceTransform(args[0], t, s)
                res = res.replace(exp, newexp)

        # otherwise don't do anything

    return res

x = Function('x')
s,t = symbols('s t')
print(laplace(Derivative(x(t), t, 3), t, s))
print(laplace(Integral(Integral(x(t), t), t), t, s))
```

The above outputs

```
s**3*LaplaceTransform(x(t), t, s)
LaplaceTransform(x(t), t, s)/s**2
```

as expected. Using your specific example:

```
I = Function('I')(t)
eq1 = integrate(I, t)
LI = laplace(eq1, t, s)
print(LI)
```

we get

```
LaplaceTransform(I(t), t, s)/s
```

which is the correct representation of "`I(s)/s`" that you expected.

---

The way the above workaround works is that it matches the arguments of the `LaplaceTransform` and checks if there's a pure `Derivative` or `Integral` inside. For `Derivative` we check that there's only differentiation with respect to `t`; this is what Eric's original workaround did, but while his code seems to have expected args of the form `Derivative(x(t), t, t, t)`, the current representation of derivatives is `Derivative(x(t), (t,3))`. This is why handling this use case had to be changed.

As for `Integral`s, the representation is similar to the original one: `Integral(x(t), t, t)` is a double integral. I still had to tweak Eric's original, because the `args` of this expression contain tuples for each integral rather than a scalar `t`, in order to accommodate definite integrals. Since we only want to handle the no-brainer case of indefinite integrals, I made sure that there's only indefinite integrals and only with respect to `t`.

If the argument of the `LaplaceTransform` is anything else, the expression is left alone.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the workaround. It solves my issue.